# Determine the projection of $\bar d$ onto the plane containing O, A and B.

Tags: vectors

$$\bar a= -i+j-k$$
$$\bar b=-2i+j-3k$$
$$\bar d=-i+2j$$

When I attempted to find the projection of $\bar d$ onto the plane OAB I just got $\bar d$ (i.e. it's in the plane). This seems odd to me, could you please verify/correct me?

I got that the unit vector normal to the plane OAB was $$\hat n=-\frac{2}{\sqrt 6}i-\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}j+\frac{1}{\sqrt 6}k$$

Comment: The inner product of $\bar{d}$ and $\hat{n}$ is zero, so $\bar{d}$ is in the plane. In fact, by inspection, we have $\bar{d} = \bar{b}-3 \bar{a}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Both results are correct. You can easily check that, since $O$ is in the plane, $\bar a \cdot \hat n = \bar b \cdot \hat n = 0$ must hold and the plane is $\{x | x\cdot \hat n = 0\}$. Now since $\bar d \cdot \hat n = 0$, you are done.

Answer (score 1):

explicitly:

$$
\bar d= \bar 3a- \bar b
$$